# Regular expression to match String Exactly with opening Round Brackets or Parentheses

Tags: c++, regex

Simple regex question. I have a string on the following format:

```
XYICD27A3 (MN PqrstUvw MFP E34540)
```

What will be the regular expression to match this string. I have tried:

```
(^([a-zA-Z0-9-_@&:.#$ s]+)$)
```

this, but it's not matching the whole string

Comment: Put `-` at the end. Remove `^` and `$`. Escape parenthesis. - [`\(([a-zA-Z0-9_@&:.#$ -]+)\)`](https://regex101.com/r/Y0G7HL/1)

Comment: Please explain more about your patter needed!?

Comment: At this point this `^[A-Z0-9]*\s\([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*\)$` completely match your string.

Comment: `std::regex(R"(\(([^()]*)\))")` is what you need, use with `regex_search`.

Comment: @navand, Thank you, it is correct for the sample string I have given.  But i need a generalized regex for this patter.  So I have modified the regex like this, ([a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)\(([a-zA-Z0-9_@&:.# -]+)\) . But it showing 3 regex matches                                       (1). XYICD27A3 (MN PqrstUvw MFP E34540)                                                                                                                
(2). XYICD27A3 
(3). MN PqrstUvw MFP E34540

Comment: Thanks @GurmanjotSingh, But using the regex only getting the string with parenthesis. I need to get a regex with full string match.

Comment: When you use parenthesis in your regex, actually you created groups. If you want only detect parenthesis in your string, you should use `\\` before parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, I corrected your regex like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+\([a-zA-Z0-9_@&:.# -]+\)
```